# Postgresql Server started .. But port(5432) is not listening

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I have install postgresql 10 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have change the configuration as below.

In pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

local   all             all                                     peer

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

In postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                     # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 500                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
```

when I check the service status on the server it's up and running.
[image]

But Port(5432) is not listening on the server.

netstat -pant | grep 5432

**nothing returned ...!**   **Please help.....!**

Comment: Can you log in using `psql`? If yes, you can run `select setting, sourcefile from pg_settings where name = 'port';` to check the actual configured value and the file in which that was configured

Comment: Also, these settings are not dynamic.   You will have to restart PostgreSQL with

    systemctl restart postgresql

for them to take effect.

Comment: I have restarted the service as well. but it was not working .. then I changed the md5 and peer with trust and restart the service . Now it's working fine. But still I have a question, Why the port is not listed to netstat command ?

Answer (score 1):

Add one more rule for ipv4 :

```
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

into pg_hba.conf

Comment: That doesn't affect the port the server process is listeneing on

Comment: isn't ::/0 ipv6 ?

Answer (score 0):

been fighting with the same error, I've changed the method for "local" type to "trust" and it's done!
[image]

Comment: local is for domain socket only, as per comments, so it must not have affected tcp listening port.